# Error con botón para descargar todas las imágenes de una galería dinámica en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

En mi pagina web tengo una galería de imágenes las cuales se cargan dinámicamente. Me pidieron de implementar un botón para descargarlas todas juntas, ***"Descargar Galería"*** lo eh llamado. Lo que primero se me vino a la cabeza fue descargar todas las imágenes y comprimirlas en un `.zip` y que éste se descargue automáticamente.

Para poder completar la tarea encontré un `Nugget Package` llamado `DotNetZip` el cual por lo que entendí es para crear archivos `.zip`. Pero cuando hago clic en el botón me salta un error

> System.Net.Sockets!System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncContext.SendToAsync(value class System.Memory`1<unsigned int8>,int32,int32,value class System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags,unsigned int8[],int32&,int32&,class System.Action`5<int32,unsigned int8[],int32,value class System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags,value class System.Net.Sockets.SocketError>,value class System.Threading.CancellationToken)"

La aplicacion es un proyecto `MVC ASP.NET`, alojada en un servidor `Linux`.

Éste es mi botón en el front:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("DescargarImagenes", "Home", new { pedido = ViewBag.pedido}, FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Descargar Galeria" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        }
```

Y este es mi botón en el controller:

```
    public FileResult DescargarImagenes(string pedido)
    {
        string consulta;
        List<PedidoViewModel> listaPedidos;

        try
        {
            listaPedidos = new List<PedidoViewModel>();
            consulta = "consultaMySql";
            listaPedidos = SelectConexionMySql(consulta);

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                foreach (var lista in listaPedidos)
                {
                    var archivo_nombre = lista.getPathImagen();
                    var archivo_arregloBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(lista.getImagenes());
                    zip.AddEntry(archivo_nombre, archivo_arregloBytes);
                }

                var nombreZip = "ImagenesPedido" + ViewBag.pedido;

                using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    zip.Save(output);
                    return File(output.ToArray(), "application/zip", nombreZip);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Las imágenes están guardadas dentro del servidor `Linux` y los paths de ellas en una base de datos, por lo que con una simple consulta las recupero y las cargo en la galería.

Para el método `DescargarImagenes`, utilizo la misma consulta que para enviar las imágenes a la galería, por lo que lo veo muy poco performance, y luego agregaría cada imagen en el zip.

Por lo que no está funcionando el botón de para descargar la galería completa. Si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería mucho!

Cualquier duda o corrección a la pregunta es bienvenida.

**Actualizacion: Éste es el Error que tengo al hacer clic en el boton**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al parecer el problema lo estoy teniendo en el `using(MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream)`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podes poner el error completo?

Comment: Eh tratado de ver el error completo mandando ViewBags a la vista de Error pero no aparecen, y no puedo poner Breakpoints ya que las imagenes están en un servidor de Linux, y no tengo imagenes en mi localhost, solo puedo correrlo haciendo un `git push`. Puedo chequearlo con un SpeedScope y lo muestro por acá

Comment: "y no tengo imagenes en mi localhost, " este es tu principal problema. Tenes que replicar el error en tu entorno, asi sea con imagenes dummy. El entorno de prueba es tan importante como el de desarrollo....

Comment: Lo siento, tuve que comentar antes, posteriormente a mi mensaje, cree las carpetas correspondientes y agregue imagenes. Procedo a poner el mensaje completo de error

Comment: buenisimo.. ahora podes seguir tu codigo y chequear porque falla...